# Excel data entry form with VBA, how to use on Sharepoint?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, data-entry

I currently have an Excel file with a data entry form- a formatted sheet with vba to provide combo boxes, validate data types & form completeness, and then load the entered data to another sheet.  I'd like to put this on Sharepoint for my team to use, but Sharepoint disables VBA.  I'd prefer that they be able to enter data online rather than downloading the Excel file and re-uploading.  Any advice on how to do this?  It's preferred if I don't have to start from scratch, but suggestions on the easiest way to implement this are also welcome.

Specifically, this is a savings tracker for a procurement group.  I'd like my team members to individually be able to enter negotiation data once complete: project name, supplier, baseline costs, negotiated value, effective date, etc.  Some fields have a list of allowed inputs- most are short lists, but the supplier list is quite long.  Their data would then be stored in a single table that I can build reports with in Power BI.  My team is not particularly tech-savvy.

Thanks!

Comment: For the online version you`ll have to create an [Office AddIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins). I recommend [Script Lab](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/script-lab/) as a starting point, helps a lot. However Sharepoint files can be sync locally with One Drive too... so you can still use the actual excel file.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  Do you mean that I'd use an Office AddIn to replace the functionality of the VBA code, or that the Office AddIn would enable the use of VBA in Excel Online?

Comment: To replace the functionality while working online (can also be used offline).

Comment: This looks like a great solution!  Unfortunately, our administrator has disabled Office 365 add-ins.  I was able to go through the Script Lab tutorial on the online version of Script Lab & this would definitely work, but I think I have to go a different route.